# Is it necessary to use `class` instead of `object` when using `isolated` for specs2 tests?

Tags: scala, specs2

For specs2 tests, we can use `object` or `class` to contain tests:

```
object MyTests extends Specification
class MyTests extends Specification
```

But if I want to use `isolated`, must I use `class`?

```
class MyTests extends Specification {
  isolated
}
```

I ask this because I found, when I use `object`, the tests sometimes reports an error:

```
NoSuchElementException: : head of empty list  (file:1)
```

But it disappeared when I change to `class`

Comment: Which version of specs2 are you using? Can you reproduce that with a simple test case (I can't)? Can you use the `fullstacktrace` argument to get the missing stacktrace?

Comment: @Eric, thanks! See here: https://github.com/realestate-com-au/pact-jvm-provider-spring-mvc/commit/d7db25c818f7ff3140b6fc883e3482f1d9008bf4 , the one in `RequestMatcherBuilderTest.scala`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug with the version of specs2 which you are using. This part has been re-implemented in specs2 3.x and is working fine.